# Swift 1.2 Array declaration, extra brackets?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Using Swift 1.2 is there a difference between `[String]` and `[(String)]` when declaring an array, or are they just the same?

```
var testArray_001: [String] = []      // Declaration = [String]
var testArray_002: [String] = Array() // Declaration = [String]
var testArray_003 = [String]()        // Declaration = [(String)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. The `(String)` form actually means *a tuple with one value of `String` type*, but it's equivalent to just saying *a `String`*.

For instance, consider the following array:

```
var array = [String]()
```

you can append a string element as usual:

```
array.append("raw string")
```

but you can also add a tuple containing one string value:

```
let tuple = (namedValue: "from tuple")
array.append(tuple)
```

Note that the equivalence doesn't stop here. If you have a function/method accepting n parameters:

```
func aFunc(#param1: Int, #param2: String, #param3: Double) {}
```

when invoking it you can provide the list of parameters:

```
aFunc(param1: 1, param2: "text", param3: 3.14)
```

but you can also group the parameters into a tuple, and just it to the function

```
let params = (param1: 1, param2: "text", param3: 3.14)
aFunc(params)
```

Comment: Thank you Antonio, thats what I was just thinking. I noticed that `var tupleArray_002 = [(Int, String)]()` declared `[((Int, String))]` and that `var tupleArray_002 = [Int, String]()` declared `[(Int, String)]` so I was starting to think that I was looking at a tuple wrapper. Thanks again for the clarification, much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious can you get the tuple function parameter list to work, I have tried it here and I am getting an error passing the tuple to the function (as per your very last line)

Comment: Which error? I've added the function to my answer, maybe you are missing the external names in its signature

Comment: The version I was trying bad 3 Int parameters `func aFunc(#param1: Int, #param2: Int, #param3: Int) {}` and gave the error: `Missing argument for parameter param2 in call` Its now working, but playgrounds seems unhappy with it as changing any of the parameters seems to kick Xcode into a downward spiral of slow, not responding and show error.